# Setup a Jenkins job that executes a protractor test suites against specific browser - which is configured in the Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I want to set in the Jenkins job the browser in which the protractor tests will be running. From Jenkins to set the capabilities in the protractor conf.js - is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass arguments into protractor cli:

```
protractor --help
Usage: protractor [options] [configFile]
Options:
  --help                                             Print Protractor help menu
  --version                                          Print Protractor version
  --browser, --capabilities.browserName              Browsername, e.g. chrome or firefox
...
```

So if you are using protractor directly it will be `protractor --browser=chrome yourconf.conf.js`
If you have grunt protractor runner it works the same, and it probably works the same in all runners.